# Adding MVC application as a subsite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a generic web application up and running `http://sites.acme.com`.
I want to add a SubSite `http://sites.acme.com/subsite1`.

In the past to add a new subsite (SubSite1), we would simply publish the project from VS into a sub folder of that folder `Sites/SubSite1`, and edit the web.config of `Sites` by adding:

```
<location path="SubSite1">    
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument enabled="true">
    <files>
      <clear/>
      <add value="index.aspx"/>
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

Now, trying to publish an mvc website, that doesn't have aspx pages, I'm trying to figure out how to get IIS to recognize that it needs to hit the SubSite1.dll in order to start the home controller, and get the index.cshtml to return.

Do I need to edit any configuration in the sites' web config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in case of MVC application we don't set default document. We set default controller and default action when we register route. For example following route registration sets default controller as "Home" controller and default action as "Index".

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Default",               // Route name
       "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

So when user types http://mysite/ then it evokes "Index" action in "Home" controller. It is as good as user typing http://mysite/Home/Index

Now, in order to setup your scenario you don't need to add default document configuration as shown in question. Just configure "subsite1" as "application" in IIS under "sites" application and you are good to go provided you have properly setup route for subsite1.

Comment: So if my subsite is in a folder named "SubSite1" and it has a default of home/index, what url should take me to my index view, `http://sites.acme.com/subsite1`?

Comment: @Steve'Kepano'Eggering: Yes. http://sites.acme.com/subsite1 will take you to default view of subsite1 application. Don't forget to configure subsite1 as "application" in IIS.

Comment: Configured as an application, and the generic sites web.config looks like this:
`<location path="subsite1">    
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>`     but I'm still getting a 500 error. Restarted IIS as well.

Comment: Check event logs and see if any error is logged there.

Comment: My problem ended up being unrelated to folder structure or naming. It wasn't working because I forgot this was a different server than the one I had been deploying on, and we hadn't installed .net core on that server yet.